# How to check creation of folders in pytest and run method only if the folders don't already exist?

Tags: python, testing, directory, pytest, fixtures

I have this fixture that creates the following folder structure:

```
-test-output
  -folder1
  -folder2
  -folder3
```

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def set_up():  
    root_path = os.getcwd()
    folders = ['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3']

    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path, 'test-output'))

    for folder in folders:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path, 'test-output', folder))


def test_folders(set_up):
    print('created folders')
```

How can I run the creation of directories, only when they haven't been created before? So far, the method runs everytime I run the test_folders method, and triggers the error:
`FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists` 
How not to run the creation of directories fixture if they are already present?

Comment: is test-output must be at same place ? you can use TemporaryDirectory from tempfile module. it create temp directory and also support cleanup to delete the temp directory after you finish the test.

Comment: @ozs it should be in the same place, because I need to further reference it in other tests

Comment: if you need this folder to create only once per session of tests then change the scope to "session" and add yield in the setup, after the yield delete the main folder. this way the creation is only once for all tests and once the tests finised you delete this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are running this fixture as `autouse=True` and  with `scope="module"`, I would recommend wrapping the function in a try statement with a few if/else's to check for the folders.

See my code below:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def set_up():
    try:
        root_path = os.getcwd()
        folders = ['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3']
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root_path, 'test-output')):
            pass
        else:
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path, 'test-output'))

        for folder in folders:
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root_path, 'test-output', folder)):
                pass
            else:
                os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path, 'test-output', folder))
    except FileExistsError as e:
        print(f'File does exist: {e}')
        pass


def test_folders(set_up):
    print('created folders')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add yield in the end of the creation. after the yield you can remove the "test-output" folder.

```
import os.path
import pytest
import shutil


@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def set_up():
    print("setup")
    root_path = os.getcwd()
    folders = ['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3']

    output_folder = os.path.join(root_path, 'test-output')
    os.mkdir(output_folder)

    for folder in folders:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path, 'test-output', folder))

    yield output_folder
    shutil.rmtree(output_folder)


def test_folders(set_up):
    print('created folders')


def test_folders1(set_up):
    print('created folders1')


def test_folders2(set_up):
    print('created folders2')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it the folders get deleted and not the test-output folder, error ``` FileExistsError``` gets triggered.

Comment: You can use tempfile.TemporaryDirectory. In this case each session of tests the path to test-output would be different. I can wdit my answer if it answer your problem